# How to call AdWords API from Android

Tags: android, google-ads-api

I trying to create app for calling AdWords API, also I need to:

1. Have ability to enable/pause campaign via a switch in the app using
   the Adwords API
2. Update campaign targeting to within a certain proximity of the
   device location at 3 min intervals

How can I call AdWords Api from Android?